# SQL query not sure if correct

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

List the username, first name, last name and date of joining of the five most recent members to register an account. List the results with the **most recent registration** first.

I've written this

```
SELECT username, first_name, last_name, join_date 
from members 
ORDER BY join_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

What's bugging me is the join_date is not the most recent. This is the result:

http://gyazo.com/6fb21d9ff93de80daf9c5530021e7fbd

Is there anything wrong with the query or am I just losing my mind? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing your `join_date` is stored as varchar instead of datetime?

Comment: The `join_date` is in an inconsistent format.  You should fix the database and store date/time using native SQL types, rather than character strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff http://gyazo.com/2277d0ed0635dcbad54fa6673b181191

Comment: @Ellie . . . Those results look like they could be correct (not knowing the original data).

Comment: @GordonLinoff http://gyazo.com/2a2cb2ee70a0ede9b112440c356c3c51 I dont know why it's not ordering.. :(

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've fixed it, basically the issue was I was DESC instead of ASC. :)! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there is a special `datetime field` for maintaining the consistency. You can also compare them as objects. The main problem is your `order by` is not working the way it has to beacuse it is not able to compare your dates.